# How to remove the iFrame DOM node that is used for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm creating a iFrame DOM dynamically only for printing.  Here's my code doing the creation and show printing window.
    var url, data, _iFrame, nonce, iframeId;

```
data = new Blob([buffer], {
   type: 'application/pdf'
});
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
_iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
nonce = (new Date()).getTime();
var iframeId = "printPDF" + nonce;
_iFrame.id = iframeId
_iFrame.setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden;');
_iFrame.setAttribute('src', url);
document.body.appendChild(_iFrame);

$('#' + iframeId)[0].focus();
$('#' + iframeId)[0].contentWindow.print();
```

But the thing is, I need to remove the iFrame after the printing is done (either print or cancel).  How can I get the event in javascript?

Comment: unfortunately `afterprint` event is only available in firefox and IE ... so that's a no go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually resolved this on my own.

The first thing is not to hide the iframe.  Instead, make it 0 size.  `style='height: 0;width: 0;'`.

Then, bind the `focus` event of the iframe and remove the iframe when it's focused again after the print dialog gets dismissed.

Well, I tried the focus event, and I failed to get into it because the iframe was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this will do the work for you:

```
$('#' + iframeId)[0].contentWindow.print();
setTimeout(function () { $('#' + iframeId)[0].contentWindow.close(); }, 100);
```